# Create singleton class for AppleLogin process

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I want to create a common manager class for apple sign in, as now a days every project needs to implement it, But I guess I'm stuck at a point where I can't compress the code and make UIviewcontroller less dependent.

This is the code I

```
import AuthenticationServices

protocol AppleLoginDelegate {
  func didCompleteWithAuthorization(responseModel: AppleLoginManager.AppleLoginResponseModel)
}

class AppleLoginManager: NSObject {
struct AppleLoginResponseModel {
    var givenName, familyName, email: String
    var identityToken: Data
    
    func getIdentityToken() -> String {
        return String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
    
private var delegate: AppleLoginDelegate
private var presentedWindow: UIViewController

init(delegate: AppleLoginDelegate, presentedWindow: UIViewController) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.presentedWindow = presentedWindow
}
    func createAppleLoginButton() -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)
    authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogInWithAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    return authorizationButton
}

// handle Apple Signin Button action
@objc private func handleLogInWithAppleIDButtonPress() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
}
```

}

```
extension AppleLoginManager: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    return self.presentedWindow.view.window!
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let credential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
        let responseData = AppleLoginManager.AppleLoginResponseModel(givenName: credential.fullName?.givenName ?? "", familyName: credential.fullName?.familyName ?? "", email: credential.email ?? "", identityToken: credential.identityToken ?? Data())
        self.delegate.didCompleteWithAuthorization(responseModel: responseData)
    }
}
}
```

This is the manager class I have created

and this is how I'm using it

```
    func setupAppleSignInButton() {
    let appleLogin = AppleLoginManager(delegate: self, presentedWindow: self)
    self.stackVew.addArrangedSubview(appleLogin.createAppleLoginButton())
}

extension ViewController: AppleLoginDelegate {
func didCompleteWithAuthorization(responseModel: AppleLoginManager.AppleLoginResponseModel) {
    print(responseModel)
}
```

}

My objective over hear is to

**1. put less code in the main controller class**

**2. don't like to put self two times at the time of initialization**

Comment: I've read your question three times now and I'm still not sure what you're asking about. If by "I can't compress the code" you mean that you'd like to reduce the amount of code needed, what part do you think isn't necessary? It's great to write compact code, but in the end you still need to do all the required tasks; if you can't find anything extraneous, maybe it's as already compact as it's going to get?

In any case, please edit to explain more clearly what help you're asking for.

Comment: I have two doubts related to this code (1.) In this code to initialize manager class I need to send self two times (isn't there a way to make it one time ? like using generics ?) (2.) I want to make this singleton class is it possible ? (In my opinion in some cases we need to show the apple signin button on two screen so singleton wouldn't be a good option I guess )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this code to initialize manager class I need to send self two times (isn't there a way to make it one time ?

You're only sending `self` twice because the same object that's initializing `AppleLoginManager` also happens to be both the delegate and the presented window. If those things must always be the same, then you could pass them as a single parameter, but it seems useful that they can be separate. Consider:

```
var house = House(owner:self, resident:self)
```

The person who owns a house and the person who lives there might not be the same person, so it's useful to pass those separately even if they often happen to be the same object.

> I want to make this singleton class is it possible ?

Sure, it's possible, but why? If the reason is just to make it easy to access your login manager, you should really rethink that. There's plenty written about singletons in other questions, so no need to rehash all of that here, but singletons are abused more often than they're used well. In your comment you suggest that you may need one of these objects in more than one place, so already it seems like a poor plan to make it a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I found a solution using the generics for my problem, may be help someone in future

I can initialize the AppleLoginManager class line this

```
init<D: AppleLoginDelegate & UIViewController>(delegate: D) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.presentedWindow = delegate
}
```

then I just need to call self once like this

```
let appleLogin = AppleLoginManager(delegate: self)
```